# How do I return something from a method to break a loop in c#?

Tags: c#, loops, methods

I'm coding a small game for myself. In this game I'm using a method which contains a loop to generate numbers into a char array that fit a specific set of criteria for use in the game. This makes the number generation, at least for my basic C# knowledge pretty convoluted and I'd like to keep it in a separate method.

The issue I have is that I need to create a loop that the player breaks themselves by pressing the quit option but if the player wants to **continue** playing it restarts the loop but **but also generates a new number from the other method.**

Should I call on that method inside the other method? If so, how do I do it?

```
public static void method2 ()  method1();
```

Should I make the loop outside the game method and thus generate a new number? If so how do I return something to quit the loop (change x to false) from a void method?

```
do method2(method 1) while (x = true)
```

I'm willing to change my method2 so it isn't a void method if anyone has a better type to use.

If someone needs specific code I can provide a link or edit the question to include it but it is pretty long (over 100 lines)!

Comment: You need to share more of your code.  We need enough that we can understand what is going on.  Ideally, we need a [mcve].

Comment: Somewhere between the 100+ lines of code you have and the invalid pseudo-C# you're showing us, there exists a simple example which demonstrates what you're trying to do and only what you're trying to do.  Create that example.  Often you'll find that the process of doing so reveals a solution before you even need to ask.  As it stands, the question(s) you're asking are vague and don't make much sense to me.  You're asking how to call a method?  How to return a value from a method?  These things are covered by introductory tutorials on the language.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly typical pattern for what I think you're describing looks like this:

```
bool keepPlaying = true;
while (keepPlaying)
{
    var number = GenerateNumber();
    // ... more code
    keepPlaying = AskIfUserWantsToPlayAgain();
}
```

However, it's perfectly fine to use other constructs to achieve the same results:

```
while (true)
{
    var number = GenerateNumber();
    // ... more code
    var keepPlaying = AskIfUserWantsToPlayAgain();
    if(!keepPlaying)
    {
        break; // or `return`, if this is your entire method.
    }
}
```